# How do I configure my CMake file to work with Google Test and CTest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, build, cmake, googletest

I am attempting to integrate the GTest framework into my project, but am not sure how to. I am using CMake to build it. I would ideally like to create a separate executable for running tests, and I would like the ability to choose to run tests on an individual module or the whole project. I'd also like it to work with CTest, but that isn't a priority. How would I set this up? My project is structured as follows:

```
3rdparty
   |--gtest
      |--include
         |--(gtest includes)
      |--lib
         |--libgtest.a
src
   |--module1
      |--file1.cpp
      |--file2.cpp
      |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--module2
      |--file3.cpp
      |--file4.cpp
      |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--CMakeLists.txt
include
   |--module1
      |--file1.hpp
      |--file2.hpp
   |--module2
      |--file3.hpp
      |--file4.hpp
test
   |--module1
       |--module1test.cpp
   |--module2
       |--module2test.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

This is my main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Aura)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include_directories(include)
add_subdirectory(src)

set (run_src
    src/run.cpp
)

add_executable(aura ${run_src})
target_link_libraries(aura util)
```

Comment: Is the file supposed to be `module2test.hpp` or `module2test.cpp` (I suspect the latter)?

Comment: module2test.cpp i edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Another question, is it necessary that you have to include gtest the way you have done so right now? i.e, Could I include/link gtest in some other way?

Comment: I would prefer it this way, but any other way is fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add test executable such just like you added target `aura` and include gtest includes and link gtest library.

Add following lines to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(3rdparty/gtest/include)
link_directories(3rdparty/gtest/lib)

add_executable(moduleTest1 moduleTest1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(moduleTest1 gtest)
```

If there are additional links with submodules you should link them as well. For example, if module1 needed, link with module1 too, e.g. `target_link_libraries(moduleTest1 gtest module1)`

Answer (score 2):

Well I can help with the concept itself and you should know how to adapt it to your project structure. So in general you want make your program structure like:

```
Structure:
 |────CMakeLists.txt
 ├─── client
            ───────CMakeLists.txt
 ├─── libs
            ───────CMakeLists.txt
 ├─── tests 
            ───────CMakeLists.txt
            ───────googletest
                              ───────googletest
                              ───────googlemock
```

top cmake can just simple include subdirectories:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(Aura)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_subdirectory(client)
add_subdirectory(test)
add_subdirectory(lib)
```

client cmake that will make your app executable will looks like that:

```
project(AuraClient)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

set(Aura-SRCS
        someSource.cpp
        main.cpp)
set(Aura-HEADERS
       someSource.h)

add_executable(Aura ${Aura-SRCS} ${Aura-HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(Aura auraLib)
```

lib where you will keep the logic code:

```
project(AuraLib)

set(lib_SRCS
        SomeLogic.cpp
        )
set(lib_HEADERS
    SomeLogic.h
        )

add_library(auraLib ${lib_SRCS} ${lib_HEADERS})
```

and your test cmake:

EDIT: just changing that cmake to less complicated solution

```
enable_testing()

project(AuraTest)

add_subdirectory(googletest)

set(test_HEADERS
        )
set(test_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        PointTest.cpp)

add_executable(AuraTest ${test_SOURCES} ${test_HEADERS} ${mock_HEADERS})

target_include_directories(AuraTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(AuraTest PRIVATE auraLib gtest gmock pthread)
```